# Xbox One S controller only vibrates and doesn't work when connected to Android using OTG

Tags: game-controllers

I just bought an Xbox One S controller (with 3.5mm jack and Bluetooth support). Whenever it's connected to a power source, it vibrates for half a second. It plays perfectly on my Windows 10 PC and my friend's Xbox console, both wireless and wired.

However, when it connects to my Android phone with an OTG cable, it only vibrates like when it's connected to a regular power source. The Xbox logo does not light up. My other two Xbox One controller (no 3.5mm jack or BT) works well with my phone so it's likely not my phone's fault.

What could be the cause for this XB1S controller to not recognize my phone? Is there any way to make it?

Comment: Android doesn’t have the necessary drivers